# Artin's presentation of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups, group-presentation

Artin presents the symmetric group $S_3$ as the group generated by $x = (123)$ and $y = (12)$, governed by the relations $x^3 = 1$, $y^2 = 1$, and $yx = x^2 y$, which yield
$$S_3 = \{1,x,x^2, y, xy, x^2 y\}.$$
It seems to me that there are others way to write this group, such as subsituting $yx$ for $x^2 y$, per the defining relation, but by brute force, I can see that these elements are distinct.

He comments, however, that we can see that these elements are distinct from the cancellation law. I'm not able to see how this is the case. Could someone point me in the right direction? I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: For instance $x^2y=y$ would imply  $x^2=1$, which is not the case.

Comment: Again, it's fairly tedious, but this time use the existence of multiplicative inverses guaranteed by the group axioms. e.g. If $x^2 = x$, then $x = 1$, contradiction. $x^2 = 1$ and $x^2 = y$ are immediate contradictions given $x = (123)$ and $y = (12)$. Now consider the same approach for $xy$ and $x^2y\dots$

Comment: All this said, a little bit of skepticism over whether the elements are _really_ distinct is a good thing; in this case it's pretty straightforward by cancellation, but in general it can be a lot harder to determine from _just_ the presentation of the group how many elements there are or when you've iterated them all uniquely.

Comment: A general comment: proving that some relation does _not_ hold in a group given by a set of generators and relations is a generally impossible task. Even in small situations, there's no obvious algorithm, etc. So it's not surprising that one wonders about such things...

Comment: Usually, if you *start* with a group defined by generators and relations, checking that it is really as big as you think it is can be a non-trivial problem, whose solution generally involves giving a representation either as a linear group or as a permutation group. In this case, you already have the action of your group on a set with $3$ elements, which is a somewhat more natural approach requiring less calculation.

Comment: One simple example of the challenges are the groups given by $\{x,y: x^4=y^2=(xy)^3=1\}$ and $\{x,y: x^4=y^2=(xy)^4=1\}$. The former has order 24; the latter is infinite...