# Let $G$ be the set of all 2×2 matrices $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ c & d \end{array}\right)%\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)\]$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices $ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d  \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $ , where $a, b, c, d$ are integers modulo $2$, such that $ad - bc\neq 0$. Using matrix multiplication as the operation in $G$, prove that $G$ is a group of order $6$

My solution goes like this :

> If $ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d  \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices where $ad-bc\neq 0$ and $a,b,c,d\in \{0,1\}$, then $|G|=6$. First we need to verify the closure property: If $A,B\in G$ then $A.B\in G$ . If $A=$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1  \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \] $ and $B=$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $ and hence, $A.B=$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $. Thus ,can we say $A.B\in G $? Also, $2$ is not an element modulo $2$ as $2\notin \{0,1\}$. But $2\in \{[0],[1]\}$. But it is specifically given in the question that $a,b,c,d$ are integers modulo $2$, which means $a,b,c,d\in {0,1}$. So, $A.B\notin G$, so closure property is not satisfied .

How can we say $G$ is a group ? If it was given that the multiplication of matrices is done modulo $2$ then $A.B\in G $ would have been valid...But its given that it is a matrix multiplication...I am not quite getting it ...

Comment: I bet the task was supposed to be about invertible matrices over field $\mathbb Z_2$. In that case, multiplication of matrices is done modulo 2 as well. If not, it is not a group.

Comment: $Det(AB)\equiv Det(A)Det(B)$ modulo 2?

Comment: @Esgeriath Well, I posted the question just as it was given in the book...and yes!multiplication of the matrices must be done modulo $2$ , otherwise  it won't be a group...

Comment: @BobDobbs That's what my question is if matrix multiplication is done modulo $2$ , it is a group , but if not how can we say thatit is a group...

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, but the group is not cyclic, so the title of your post is wrong.

Comment: That $2$ you got should really be $[2]$. And because we work modulo two, we also have $[2]=[0]$. The same with all the matrix entries. They are no longer integers, instead they are residue classes.

Comment: This is the group [$GL(2,2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116877/order-of-gl2-mathbbz-2-list-all-elements), which is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't know about it..The one who edited my post actually changed the title...so I don't know why he did that ....anyways I changed it back to the original title...Thank you!...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I do get it that $[2]=[0]$ in case of congruence residue classes but, we can't really show that closure property is satisfied as it is given a normal matrix multiplication as the binary operation (and not matrix multiplication modulo $2$)

Comment: @Franklin You seem to be unclear about the definition of matrix operations. A matrix has entries in a specified field (or more generally a ring) $K$ such as the real numbers or the rational numbers of the integers modulo $p$ for a prime number $p$. Then, by definition,  multiplication and addition of matrices is carried out using the operations of the field $K$. So in this case, $K$ is the field of integers modulo $2$, and hence matrix operations are carried out using that the operations of that field.

Comment: @Franklin : $... \text{ and }\left[ 1 \right]=\left[ -1 \right]=\left[ -3 \right]=...$; "integers modulo 2" [what is written on the question you are working on] are not integers but classes of integers; I prefer to note without the usual abuse of language:$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{2\mathbb{Z},1+2\mathbb{Z}\}$. By the way, it makes no sense to write $2\in \{[0],[1]\}$, as it is written in the post, . On the other hand, it would make sense to write $2 \in [0]$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually,I am still learning about basic group theory and and I have no idea about ring or field.But do we require those concepts here?As in the book it was given in the group theory chapter maybe as a beginning exercise...I think the question is unclear on the part that although it says that the entries in the matrix are integers modulo $2$, then it might be from the set $S=\{0,1\}$.I considered it from $S$ as if the entries are congruence classes then why is it given as "integers modulo 2" ...Now, since$2\in [0]$so if we do multiplication mod $2$ it becomes a valid element ...

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I think the question is unclear on the part that although it says that the entries in the matrix are integers modulo $2$, then it might be from the set $S=\{0,1\}$.I considered it from $S$ as if the entries are congruence classes then why is it given as "integers modulo 2" ...Now, since$2\in [0]$so if we do multiplication mod $2$ it becomes a valid element in the group and closure property is satisfied . However, if we consider the entries of the matrix as the congruence classes then also it becomes a valid element...as the set $S=\{[0],[1]\}$ is being considered here...

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen But if we simply say multiplication(and not multiplication $mod p$) as the binary operation then G is not a group...

Comment: You wrote that you "have no idea about ​​ring or field"; know that in the mind of the person who posed the exercise, multiplication means multiplication $mod 2$, before learning more soon... :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Thanks a lot! I do get it now..if multiplication means multiplication $mod2$ here, then it's valid and G is a group as well...Thank you!...

Comment: You have been advised before not to use . for multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K:=\mathbb{F}_{2}$. G represents the group of $K$-linear transformations of $(\mathbb{F}_{2})^2$ for example. In basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, $G=\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1\\0 &1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $b=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\1 &1\end{matrix}\right]$. Then, $a^2=b^3=e=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0\\0 &1\end{matrix}\right]$ and also $b^2=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$, $ab=\left[\begin{matrix} 1& 0\\1 &1\end{matrix}\right]$, $ab^2=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\1 &0\end{matrix}\right]$ genarating all elements. We have alo the relation $aba=b^2$.
Hence, $G=\left<a,b|a^2=b^3=abab=e\right>$ which is isomorphic to $S_3$. See: [Artin's presentation of $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147009/artins-presentation-of-s-3)

Comment: I don't quite get it...I wanted to ask that if $A=$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \] $ and $B=$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $ and hence, $A.B=$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{array} \right) % \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \] $  but then $A.B\notin G$ if we consider simple matrix multiplication(and not multiplication modulo $2$). So how is this a group ?

Comment: We consider $GL(2,\Bbb F_2)$, so $2=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde actually I am still learning about basic group theory ....so I am not quite familar with the $\mathbb{F}_2$  notation,  ur using ?...

Comment: It is the symmetry group of the set $\{(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}$ under the action of $GL(2,\Bbb{F}_2)$. This triangle is not equileteral.

Comment: @DietrichBurde will forgive me for answering for him. But, as a Frenchman, it's a question that interests me because I asked myself: indeed, instead of saying "[F]ield", we say "[C]orps" in French; $\mathbb{F}_2$ designates the Field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Yes, exactly. $\Bbb Z/2$ is a finite field, often denoted by $\Bbb F_2$.